# js code inside script tags of HTML5 work but not in external js file

Tags: javascript, html

If this code is inside script tags in index.html it works fine but when moving this code to a js file referenced in the head it no longer works. One thought I had was to use window.onload but was not able to get that working. This is for a simple local HTML5 video player. It's been a while since I worked with external js. Can anyone help me out?

```
var myVideo = document.getElementById("myVideo");

function playPause() {
  var el = document.getElementById("playButton");
  if (myVideo.paused) {
    myVideo.play();
    el.className ="";
  } else {
  
    myVideo.pause();
    el.className = "playButton";
  }
}
myVideo.addEventListener("click", playPause, false);
var pause42 = function(){
    if(this.currentTime >= 13 && !myVideo.paused) {
      this.currentTime = 42;
        this.pause();

        // remove the event listener after you paused the playback
        this.removeEventListener("timeupdate",pause42);
    }
};
myVideo.addEventListener("timeupdate", pause42);

var pause49 = function(){
    if(this.currentTime >= 45 && !myVideo.paused) {
      this.currentTime = 49;
        this.pause();

        // remove the event listener after you paused the playback
        this.removeEventListener("timeupdate",pause49);
    }
};
myVideo.addEventListener("timeupdate", pause49);
```

Comment: See [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/4642212). Is your `<script>` _above_ your HTML with no `defer` attribute and no `DOMContentLoaded` or `load` listener? See [Why does jQuery or a DOM method such as `getElementById` not find the element?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14028959/4642212). [What Do You Mean “It Doesn’t Work”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/147616/289905) Use the [browser console (dev tools)](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`) and read any errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap `var myVideo = document.getElementById("myVideo")` in a `DOMContentLoaded` event so the HTML element is loaded before trying to get the element in your JS file.

Then add your event listeners inside the same function as below.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
    var myVideo = document.getElementById("myVideo");
    myVideo.addEventListener("click", playPause, false);
    myVideo.addEventListener("timeupdate", pause42);
    myVideo.addEventListener("timeupdate", pause49);
});
```